# How do i set Google spreadsheets to email each row daily with a specific subject? (Automatically)

Tags: email, google-apps-script, buffer, spreadsheet

I would like to email the Google spreadsheet rows daily, with a 
specific SUBJECT, without me having to anything.
I have 4500 rows, which I would like emailed daily.

I have 4500 tweets which i would like tweeted.
The plan is to send all those rows (via Email) to Buffer, which will then be tweeted.

alternatively how do i send all those rows daily to my buffer schedule?

here's a link to 300 of those rows https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pFaMzeEfXUCzgVbUzcXZE6UiWW5PAkxdkOC_zogEQ6g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Post the code you already tried and need help, not your requirements. In the meantime read the docs about apps script daily quotas because you wont have enough.

Comment: i have never used a code, i just saw a tutorial that showed me it's possible to use a Script to send emails via a spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes its possible and tutorials show examples. But this forum is for coding problems you might need help, not for someone to write the code from a spec.